# How do I convert my CASE WHEN THEN statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Please help me to convert the below statement:

```
CASE 
  WHEN TITLE IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'
  WHEN LOCAL_TITLE IS NOT NULL THEN 'B'
  END
AS COMBINED_TITLE
```

to something like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN TITLE IS NOT NULL THEN COMBINED_TITLE=TITLE
  WHEN LOCAL_TITLE IS NOT NULL THEN COMBINED_TITLE=LOCAL_TITLE
  END
AS COMBINED_TITLE
```

Thanx in advance
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you're trying to set a variable, you would do this:

```
SELECT
    @CombinedTitle = CASE
        WHEN Title IS NOT NULL THEN Title
        WHEN Local_Title IS NOT NULL THEN Local_Title
    END
...
```

If you still want to create column `Combined_Title` but with values from the two title columns, you would do:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Title IS NOT NULL THEN Title
        WHEN Local_Title IS NOT NULL THEN Local_Title
    END AS Combined_Title
...
```

Also see [documentation on `COALESCE`](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ca-co_8.htm), it even mentions that it is equivalent to a `CASE` statement just like yours (with the addition of `ELSE NULL`.)

Comment: thanx Blixt, your second select is what I am after, unfortunately it does not work in SQL Server 2005...

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to use it in an update statement? You could actually do away with the CASE statement in this instance

```
UPDATE
    <table>
SET
    COMBINED_TITLE = COALESCE(TITLE, LOCAL_TITLE, COMBINED_TITLE)
```

COALESCE will find the first NON-NULL value in the list

Answer (score 2):

[ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(SQL.90).aspx)(TITLE, LOCAL_TITLE) AS COMBINED_TITLE

Comment: Be wary though, if both TITLE and LOCAL_TITLE are NULL, this will set COMBINED_TITLE to NULL (although this may be want is required in this case)